# Given a strictly positive number, can I always find an epsilon such that it's smaller and its inverse is larger?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

Suppose I have a number $x$ that is strictly positive $x>0$. Is it true that I can find a number $\epsilon >0$ such that

- $\epsilon$ is smaller than or equal to $x$
- $x$ is smaller than or equal to $1/\epsilon$

$$\epsilon \leq x \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

To me this seems always possible because:

- Suppose $x\in [1, +\infty)$. Then clearly I can take $\epsilon:=\frac{1}{x}$ and this does the job, because $\epsilon\leq 1\leq x$ and $\frac{1}{\epsilon}=x$ and so $x\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}=x$.
- Suppose $x\in(0, 1)$. Then, once I find $\epsilon \leq x$ clearly $\frac{1}{\epsilon}>1>x$.

Is there a more formal proof? Does this property have a name, if it is true?

Comment: For the first case, if $\epsilon$ were indeed $\frac{1}{x}$ you would have $\epsilon < x<\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ would have instead read as being $\frac{1}{x}<x<\frac{1}{1/x}$ after plugging things in or rather $\frac{1}{x}<x<x$.  Note that $x$ is not strictly smaller than itself, so the second inequality there fails.  Try $\frac{1}{2x}$ instead.

Comment: $\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} \left( \epsilon, \epsilon^{-1} \right) = (0, \infty)$. Also, it seems that you have mixed up $<$ and $\leq$.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I meant $\leq$, not $<$.

Comment: I think its slightly more interesting to prove the version with $<$ instead., it doesn't require much more effort and is a stronger result...

Comment: @JMoravitz agreed! I just thought about proving this because I was wondering if it was possible or not, but I agree that the property with $<$ is more interesting and powerful.

Comment: How about $\epsilon = \min\{x,1/x\}$? Or, for the strict inequality version, $\epsilon = \min\{x/2,2/x\}$?

Comment: @LeeMosher something is off there.  For $x=2$ both would result in $1$, but $1<2<\frac{1}{1}$ is false.  I think you mean $\frac{1}{2x}$ there instead of $\frac{2}{x}$, as my first comment would have alluded to which would have led to $\frac{1}{4}<2<4$.

Comment: Oops, you're right. @JMoravitz

Comment: The 2nd supposition is a failure.